# Nivo Slider breaks after I navigate away and back to home page while using Ajax

Tags: ajax, jquery, nivo-slider

I'm using a Nivo Slider in a website that uses Ajax to load its content. It saves the user from loading new pages every time they click on a link.

My problem is that when I load the home page initially, the slider works fine; but if I navigate away from that page then back to it, it just has the loading gif on a loop. Can anyone help?

My `index.php` is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>I.C.T - St. Patrick's Academy, Lisburn</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jqmin.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/js.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/nivo.css" media="all" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/sliderpack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/slide.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="wrap">
      <div id="head">
        <div id="links">
          <ul>
            <li><a href="includes/home.php" class="left">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="includes/about.php">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="includes/contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="includes/learn.php" class="right">Learn</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <img src="assets/images/logo.png" alt="logo" />
      </div>
      <div id="screen">
        <div id="pad"></div>
        <div id="cont_wrap">
          <div id="cont">
            <h2>Home</h2>
            <div class="slider-wrapper">
              <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">
                <img src="assets/images/slide1.jpg" alt="1" />
                <img src="assets/images/slide2.jpg" alt="2" />
                <img src="assets/images/slide3.jpg" alt="3" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="foot">
        <p align="center"><i>Copyright 2013 - Finbar Maginn - St. Patrick's Academy, Lisburn</i></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(Note that my Nivo Slider initialization is inside `slide.js` and looks like this:)

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#slider').nivoSlider({
    effect: 'random', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices: 16, // For slice animations
    boxCols: 6, // For box animations
    boxRows: 3, // For box animations
    animSpeed: 1000, // Slide transition speed
    pauseTime: 5000, // How long each slide will show
    startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
    directionNav: false, // Next & Prev navigation
    controlNav: false, // 1,2,3... navigation
    controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav
    pauseOnHover: false, // Stop animation while hovering
    manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
    prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
    nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
    randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
    beforeChange: function(){}, // Triggers before a slide transition
    afterChange: function(){}, // Triggers after a slide transition
    slideshowEnd: function(){}, // Triggers after all slides have been shown
    lastSlide: function(){}, // Triggers when last slide is shown
    afterLoad: function(){} // Triggers when slider has loaded
  });
});
```

The Ajax jQuery file I'm using is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
  var href = $('#links li a').each(function(){
    var href = $(this).attr('href');
    if(hash==href.substr(0,href.length-3)){
      var toLoad = hash+'.php #cont';
      $('#cont').load(toLoad)
    }
  });
  $('#links li a').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #cont';
    $('#cont').fadeOut('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#wrap').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('fast');
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-4);
    function loadContent() {
      $('#cont').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());
    }
    function showNewContent() {
      $('#cont').fadeIn('fast',hideLoader('fast'));
    }
    function hideLoader() {
      $('#load').fadeOut('fast');
    }
    return false;
  });
});
```

And here is my CSS:

```
body {
  font-size:95%;
  font-family:georgia;
  line-height:1.576;
}
h2 {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#wrap {
  margin:0 auto;
  width:784px;
}
#head {
  width:100%;
  height:175px;
}
#links {
  width:300px;
  height:30px;
  padding:140px 0 0 0;
  float:right;
  text-align:right;
}
#links ul {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
#links ul li {
  display:inline;
  margin:0 -2px 0 -2px;
}
#links ul li a {
  font-size:1em;
  -webkit-transition: 0.1s;
  -moz-transition: 0.1s;
  -ms-transition: 0.1s;
  -o-transition: 0.1s;
  text-decoration:none;
  color:black;
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #74b998);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #74b998);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #74b998);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(bottom, white, #74b998);
  padding:3px 5px 3px 5px;
}
#links ul li a:hover {
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, white, #74b998);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(top, white, #74b998);
  background:-ms-linear-gradient(top, white, #74b998);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #74b998);
  padding:7px 5px 7px 5px;
}
.left {
  border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  -o-border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
  border-top-left-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-top-left-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-top-left-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-top-left-radius:10px;
  -o-border-top-left-radius:10px;
}
.right {
  border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  -o-border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-top-right-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-top-right-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-top-right-radius:10px;
  -o-border-top-right-radius:10px;
}
.radius {
  border-radius:10px;
  -webkit-border-radius:10px;
  -moz-border-radius:10px;
  -ms-border-radius:10px;
  -o-border-radius:10px;
}
#screen {
  width:100%;
  height:480px;
  background-image:url(../images/bckgrnd.png);
}
#pad {
  width:100%;
  height:29px;
}
#cont_wrap {
  overflow:auto;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:724px;
  height:335px;
  padding: 0 0 0 6px;
}
#load {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 950px;
  text-indent: -9999em;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: url(../images/load.gif) no-repeat;
}
#cont {
}
#foot {
  width: 100%;
  font-size:90%;
  color:gray;
}
#slider {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 700px;
  height: 273px;
}
.nivoSlider {
  position: relative;
  background: url(../images/load.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
.nivoSlider img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: none;
}
.nivoSlider a {
  border: 0;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: depending on your version of jQuery you will need to use the `on` or `live` methods or just re-initialise the slider when you load the page that uses it

Comment: I'm using the one that came with the most recent nivo slider jQuery download, as far as I remember its 1.9.0

Comment: ok, try in your `loadContent()` function, put the same nivoslider inititalisation code, I *think* that should work.

Comment: should add that you should only initialise the slider when it's the home content you are loading, easy way to do that would be to add an id to your links and check what it is when you click one.

Comment: Ok I'll try it out, im not very strong when it comes to OOP so forgive me if I ask any stupid questions. I take it I should put the initializing code after 'function loadContent() {
      $('#cont').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());'

Comment: don't worry, I'm terrible at OO! Yeah, initalise it after the markup for the slider has been loaded.

Comment: Ok, I placed the initializing code straight after the showNewContent()); and no luck, even tried taking out $(window).load and no joy, how would I go about checking for the link id?

Comment: `$('#links li a').click(function(){ var id = $(this).attr('id');` don't know why it's not working though because it is something like this that needs to be done to get the slider to work again

Comment: Should I try a different version of jQuery? Maybe 1.8.2? I dont know enough about jquery development so its just a thought. I do enjoy developing but when it comes to something like this it just wrecks my head

Comment: nah, the version is fine, it's just that the methods I mentioned, `live` and `on` are used so that the event triggers on any future elements added to the page,e.g. if you had a click function and you fetched more content via ajax, the click function wouldn't work on those two elements without using `live` or `on` and `live` is for versions < 1.7 and `on` is used for versions after that. Have you got a live page or a dev version that is publicly accessible?

Comment: Not currently, I'll load it somewhere and post the link to let you see

Comment: heres the link to the site im currently developing, i found that loading it online causes some issues with the fadeIn() and fadeOut() you will be able to see for yourself.

http://www.urbanartscentre.com/finbarmaginn/stpatsict/

Comment: I'm also wondering if the ajax is affecting the file path to the sliders images but if that where the case I wouldn't be getting the loading gif

Comment: ah, aswell as what I said earlier, you might need to include your sliderpack.js and slide.js in home.php aswell. I'm purely guessing though as it's not easy to troubleshoot when you don't have the stuff at your fingertips to play around with.

Comment: yea i had tried putting the different JS files in a load of different places includeing the home.php but with no luck, thats why i turned to stackoverflow :S